# How to fix the Design Configuration grid empty?

Tags: magento2, admin, theme, design, magento-cloud

I'm running a Magento 2.3 Cloud and I saw the grid before, but after installing a theme I can't see the default options in my design grid anymore, it's in the **Admin panel > Content > Design > Configuration**.

[image: Magento 2.3 design grid empty]

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The design grid depends on an index called `design_config_grid`, which means that by running these commands below you might be able to see your grid again.

```
bin/magento indexer:status
bin/magento indexer:reset design_config_grid
bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid
bin/magento cache:clean
```